# Private function and null safe operator testing in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, testing, exception, bad-request, error-code

I am trying to improve the test coverage, but I am confused about some lines that are considered as "not covered" or "only partially covered" such as:

```
400 -> throw BadRequestException(response.code(), response.errorBody()?.string())
```

and

```
if (response.code() !in 200..299) {
      throwError(response)
}
```

throwError is a private function. I am testing that, with a response code 204, there is a success event and 400, there is the right error that is thrown. But how to check that throwError is called?

Also, when I check that the error BadRequestException is thrown, why only 1 or 2 conditions are met?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first case, the two conditions should be:

1. `response.errorBody()` is `null`
2. `response.errorBody()` is not `null`

So you need to cover both to have it completely covered.

Comment: Thank you, what should I test then? That when it is not null, toString() is not called, and when it null, it is not called?

Comment: You don't need to test everything in your code. Aiming for 100% test coverage is non-sense and counterproductive. You should test the core features of your application not every single condition in it. But if you really want to you would need to test that the Response body is either null or not (depending if `response.errorBody()` is null or not).